# Trigger Shift tab event using native javascript

Tags: javascript

i am working on implementing accessibility for my client site, in one of the case, i need to go back to the previous DOM element, previous element could be input, radio, link in this case, i need to trigger SHIFT & TAB event to go back to previous focusable element.

i need some thing like

```
document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
```

for SHIFT & TAB

i have tried with multiple options have not found any solutions any help would be appreciated.